# Worse performance when using a bigger multiple work group size of CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE

Tags: opencl

I am writing a matrix multiplication program in OpenCL. In order to utilize local memory, I divided the original matrix into `block_size * block_size` sub-matrix, where `block_size` is equals to a square root of `work group size` and will be calculated in one work group.

My GPU is *RX580*, and `CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` returns `256`, so a square root is `16`, while `CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE` returns `64`. And **after some profiling, I found out that settting the `block_size` to `8*8` performs 4 times faster than setting it to `16*16`, which seems unintuitive to me.** Any explanation to this?

EDIT: CodeXL screenshot

8*8 work group
[image]
[image]

16*16 work group
[image]
[image]

I noticed something unusual. How can `SALUBusy%` exceed 100% in the 8*8 work group case?

EDIT2: Add my kernel code, which might be useful

```c
size_t getIndex(int row, int col, int width)
{
    return row*width+col;
}


__kernel void matrixMul(__global const float* restrict a, 
    __global const float* restrict b,  //assume tranposed
    __local float* restrict a_local,
    __local float* restrict b_local,
    __global float* restrict result) 
{
    const int row=get_global_id(0);
    const int col=get_global_id(1);

    const int limit=get_global_size(0);


    const int blockSize=get_local_size(0);
    const int gidRow=get_local_id(0);
    const int gidCol=get_local_id(1);

    
    float sum=0;
    for(int blockIndex=0; blockIndex < (limit/blockSize); ++blockIndex)
    {
        /*copy block -> local memory*/
        a_local[getIndex(gidRow, gidCol, blockSize)]=a[getIndex(row, col, limit)];
        b_local[getIndex(gidRow, gidCol, blockSize)]=b[getIndex(row, col, limit)];
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        /*block multiply*/
        __local float* restrict a_local_row=&a_local[getIndex(gidRow, 0, blockSize)];
        __local float* restrict b_local_row=&b_local[getIndex(gidCol, 0, blockSize)];
        for(int i=0; i<blockSize; ++i)
        {
            sum+= (*a_local_row) * (*b_local_row);
            ++a_local_row;
            ++b_local_row;
        }
    }

    result[getIndex(row, col, limit)]=sum;
}
```

Comment: The more local memory is being used the less resources available at runtime = less number of workgroups that can be run simultaneously. That may be the case here too. Anyway in codexl you should be able to find an answer to your question by profiling your app.

Comment: @doqtor I added the screenshot of CodeXL, and can't think of an explanation.

Comment: What is the size of the original matrix?

Comment: @doqtor It's 2048*2048, as you can see from the screenshot ``GlobalWorkSize``

Comment: Matrix 2048x2048 requires 128 workgroups for 16x16 and 256 for 8x8. For 16x16 block size we can squeeze 16 workgroups per compute unit (40 for 8x8). That gives us 256 / 40 = 6.4 = 7 compute units needed for 16x16 and 256 / 128 = 2 compute units needed for 8x8. The device got 36 compute units but how many can run simultaneously you would need to check in spec.

Comment: It might be also due to the fact that wavefront size is 64 so that fits 8x8 block size inside one wavefront.

Comment: @doqtor Did you forget to multiply the second dimension? 2048*2048 divided into 16*16 work group is 16384 total work groups. Both of the case should be saturate all compute units so I don't think it is the case here.

Comment: Yep, you are right I forgot about 2nd dim. In that case have a closer look at local memory. [Here](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_Optimization_Guide2.pdf) read 2.2 Local Memory (LDS) Optimization. This is old document but gives some ideas, you may want to try finding a doc talking about your GPU.